# TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python-3.x

Здравствуйте, в python еще неопытент
Написал следующий код:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
res = urlopen("...")
string = res.read()
url=""
try:
    start = string.index("display_src")
    start+=15
    url = string[start:string.index(",",start)]
except ValueError:
    print("ValueError")
print(url)
```

Получил следующию ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ivan/PycharmProjects/Instagram/get_origin_photo.py", line 6, in <module>
    start = string.index("display_src")
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

В гугл ответа пока не нашел. Подскажите в чем соль.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Понял в чем проблема.
Помогло следущие решение:

```
string = str(res.read())
```